# Tcl variable substitution inside $::

Tags: variables, tcl, substitution

If I define the following list:

```
set ::listofvariablesn [list {"inputfile" "Input file"}]
set ::inputfile "Somefile or numbers"
```

I can check if the variable ::inputfile exists using:

```
foreach a $::listofvariablesn {
   if {[info exists ::[lindex $a 0]]} {
      puts "Ok" 
   }
}
```

But I cannot access the value of ::inputfile using:

```
foreach a $::listofvariablesn {   
    if {[checkvl "Input file" $::[lindex $a 0] 1 0 0 0]} { 
        puts "Ok" 
    }
}
```

I got the error:
can't read "::": no such variable

Is there a way to get this substitution done? I mean turn $::[lindex $a 0] into $::inputfile so I can access the value of ::inputfile

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` is a shortcut, and can't do double substitution.
Use the `set` command:

```
if {[checkvl "Input file" [set ::[lindex $a 0]] 1 0 0 0]} {
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. This works perfectly. Changing my code tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the longhand form of `$`, the one-argument form of the `set` command, there is also the option to create an alias of the variable (with a known name) using `upvar 0`. For example:

```
upvar 0 $a b
puts "exists: [info exists b]" 
puts "value: $b"
```

Anything you do to the variable `b` (except changing the `upvar`) will be performed on the variable that was named by `$a`.